# zod schema not triggering required_error for empty strings

Tags: forms, next.js, schema, next.js13, zod

I'm using the `zod` library to validate a form in my Next.js application. I've defined a schema for a subscription form that should validate an `email` field. I want to display a custom error message - `Email is required` - when the `email` field is left empty, but for some reason, the `required_error` property isn't working as expected. If I click on `Subscribe` without entering any email, I get the error message `Email is invalid`, instead of the error message `Email is required`.

[image]

Here's my schema:

```
export const subscribeSchema = z.object({
  email: z
    .string({ required_error: "Email is required" })
    .email({ message: "Email is invalid" }),
});
```

Here's is how I am using the schema in the Subscribe form:

```
"use client";

import * as React from "react";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import * as z from "zod";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

import { cn } from "@/lib/util";
import { subscribeSchema } from "@/lib/validations/auth";
import { buttonVariants } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";
import { Label } from "@/components/ui/label";
import { Icons } from "@/components/icons";
import { subscribeUser } from "@/lib/subscribe-user";

export type FormData = z.infer<typeof subscribeSchema>;

export function SubscribeForm() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    reset,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<FormData>({ resolver: zodResolver(subscribeSchema) });

  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
  const [error, setError] = React.useState<string | null>(null);

  const router = useRouter();

  async function onSubmit(submittedData: FormData) {
    await subscribeUser({
      submittedData,
      setError,
      router,
      setIsLoading,
      reset,
    });
  }

  return (
    <div className="grid gap-6 rounded-md border border-neutral-200 bg-neutral-100 p-6">
      <div className="flex flex-col space-y-1">
        <h1 className="text-2xl">Subscribe</h1>
        <p>Get notified of the course launch.</p>
      </div>
      {error && (
        <p className="text-sm text-red-500 animate-in fade-in-0 slide-in-from-left-1">
          {error}
        </p>
      )}
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <div className="grid gap-6">
          <div className="grid gap-1">
            <Label htmlFor="email">Email</Label>
            <Input
              className="bg-white"
              id="email"
              type="email"
              placeholder="name@example.com"
              autoCapitalize="none"
              autoComplete="email"
              autoCorrect="off"
              disabled={isLoading}
              {...register("email")}
            />
            {errors.email && (
              <p className="px-1 text-xs text-red-600 animate-in fade-in-0 slide-in-from-left-1">
                {errors.email.message}
              </p>
            )}
          </div>
          <button className={cn(buttonVariants())} disabled={isLoading}>
            {isLoading && (
              <Icons.spinner className="mr-2 h-4 w-4 animate-spin" />
            )}
            Subscribe
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Has anyone encountered this issue before? Is there something I'm missing in my schema definition?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

An input field returns an empty string even when no input is provided. The `required_error` property in Zod triggers only if the field is not registered, not when it’s an empty string.

To handle this, you can use Zod’s `.min(1)` validation. This checks that the string length is at least 1, ensuring the field isn’t empty. Here’s how you can adjust your schema:

```
export const subscribeSchema = z.object({
  email: z
    .string()
    .min(1, { message: "Email is required" }) // Makes sure the email field isn't empty
    .email({ message: "Email is invalid" }), // Checks if it's a valid email
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This solution might help  if you are using React-form-hook

You can utilize the setValueAs option in the register function provided by React Hook Form.

```
<input
register={register("email", {
    setValueAs: (value) => {
        if (value === "") return undefined;
        return value;
    }
})}
name="email"
/>
```

By setting the value to undefined when it's empty, you can ensure that zod will recognize it as a required field